# C# - Converting string into nullable Guid?

Tags: c#, nullable, guid

Is there an easier way of converting a string into a `Guid?`? Just now I have this code:

```
if (Guid.TryParse(request.QueryStringParameters["key"], out Guid result))
{
    whateverFunction(result);
}
else
{
    whateverFunction(null);
}
```

I was hoping there would be an easier way such as casting to `(Guid?)` or doing `new Guid?()` however neither of them seem to work. This needs to happen a lot of times in my program, obviously I can just put it in a function and that would be fine but hoping there is a cleaner way of doing this.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, you can write your code like this:

```
var nullableGuid = Guid.TryParse(request.QueryStringParameters["key"], out var result)
    ? result
    : (Guid?)null;

whateverFunction(nullableGuid);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just write your own method:

```
public Guid? TryParseGuid(string input)
{
   if (Guid.TryParse(input, out Guid result))
   {
       return result;
   }
   else
   {
       return null;
   }
}
```

You can use it the following way:

```
whateverFunction(TryParseGuid(request.QueryStringParameters["key"]));
```

Answer (score 1):

if your application is heavily used string guids, then use extension instead :

```
public static class AppExtension
{
    public static Guid? ToGuid(this string source)
    {
        return Guid.TryParse(source , out Guid result) ? (Guid?) result : null;
    }
}
```

usage would be :

```
var guidStr = "6b97c671-8cc4-4712-b3df-9dad09321a36";
var guid = guidStr.ToGuid();
```